# include sql enterprise in setup project?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

## include sql enterprise in setup project?

**how to include sql enterprise when it's not appear in prerequisites of the setup project**

**and if it's not possible do i have install the full enterprise edition on the client machine?**
i use visual studio 2010 and sql enterprise 2008.
**i'm a database beginner** and i always used to use sql express edition but now data base getting grow fast and the limitations of the sql express for 4gb make a big problem so any help i will be grateful

Comment: Can you explain how you will be using the SQL Server after it is installed? Is this for a product that you are distributing?  Or is it for a single installation that your project uses in production?  Or do you just need it for your development environment?  I ask because SQL Server Enterprise is a pretty big and complicated installation procedure, and it has a pretty big licence cost as well.

Comment: all my database interaction will be through linq to sql.the application save alot amount of date and the data base grow fast. the client will bay for the licence.

Comment: Again, one client?  Or is this a product and you will have many clients?

Comment: many clients application

Comment: Installing an enterprise-grade central DB server is a bit different to installing express. I don't think this is desirable, let alone possible.

Comment: It is better that you set the presence of SqlServer Enterprise Edition as prerequisite of your application and focus your efforts to create a step-by-step guide for your user. Call it "How to install and prepare SQL Server Enterprise for MyApp".

Comment: i think there no easy way as i thought but really thanks all. from the next project i will depend on mysql and linq to object

Comment: For what it's worth: No product that I know of tries to do this, not even Microsoft's own biggest products: Sharepoint, CRM, etc.  They do all require SQL Server Standard or Enterprise, however, they specify it as a pre-requisite:  The customer must install it first.

Comment: I think that you may be over-looking another important issue here.  When your product database needs start reaching these levels, it is no longer appropriate for the Client Product to be telling the customer where the database should be.  Instead, things should now be reversed, the customer now adds your database to whichever server  and on whatever storage best suits their need be it NAS, a giant SAN farm, etc.  And then they tell your client-product where to find it through means that your provide to them.  That is how it is generally done.

Comment: ok this is quite a lot of work to do (networking & database administration is not of my skills ) is there any way to patch or make any thing to sql express to make it be more than 4gb and i will put it in shred folder like i always do (no a good move but it do the trick) all what concern me right now my database grow up fast and i don't know what could be happen after 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Microsoft SQL Enterprise** edition follows and uses it's own License, you need to install it through the Web or offline Setup only.

It's a paid licence product, witch Express and Compact Editions are not, and this last two editions are the ones that you can pack with your application as **their licenses allow you to do so**.

You can always use a file that can run on a database to populate with records, or use, for example, [Windows SQL Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/sql-azure/) to have a centered database and Export / Import your schema with data.

Comment: thanks for this solution i will try sql azure for now and for the next app i will stick for mysql